# Form: passing data UTF8 to another page

Tags: php, utf-8, header

I'm posting (`$_POST[]`) data from page A and try to output it on page B, however something isn't working with `UTF8`.

The data on page B is (I believe) not in `UTF8`, for example `é` becomes `?`. If I use `utf8_encode` on page B it's all fine again.

The tricky part is that `mb_detect_encoding()` does return `UTF-8`on page B for the data from `POST`

So on page A I have all headers set to UTF8

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

And after my mysql connection

```
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
```

The form on page A has

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

and page B is loaded with Ajax and has also the header on

Am I missing something? Or should I always use `utf8_encode()` on data from `POST` ?

Comment: What happens if you echo the data on page A?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in Config page itself. So it will be used in all pages as you need that.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from page A to B, do you use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) ? This function is exclusively  used for data encoded into utf-8

Comment: no I'm not doing anything at all. Just trying to print `$_POST['text'];`

Comment: Yes but if you use Ajax, how do you pass data between your two pages ?

Comment: Ah, with XMLHttpRequest(). I tried to set a header in there as UTF8 aswell, but not changing anything

Comment: I can advice you to use json to pass your data like this: http://chez-syl.fr/2012/01/envoyer-un-formulaire-en-ajax-avec-jquery-et-json/
I used this example few days ago, and no issue with utf-8. Hope it helps you!